# How to Support User Selectable Locales in AngularJS Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization

It sounds like this question has been asked a few times before, but I am not seeing a solution.  So here goes the question!

I am using the date filter in an HTML page of an AngularJS application to display dates in a page as follows:

```
{{item.dateCreated | date:'mediumDate'}}
```

I have a menu item on my page that allows the user to select the language to be used to display the page.  I am using the excellent ngTranslate module to perform the translation of the strings on the page, but it does not handle the date display above.

The AngularJS docs indicate that there is a $locale service with one member called id - not sure if this is a property to view the locale or a method to set it.  The docs also say that I need to include the i18n script file appropriate for the locale in the page after the angularjs library has been included, but of course I don't know the locale until runtime when the user selects it.

So the question is, how can I support multiple locales in an angularjs application such that filters such as **date** translate and format dates for the locale, and how do I tell angularjs what locale to use if the user changes it at runtime?  I suppose I could build a set of format strings by hand and apply them to the date filter as the user selects a language, but that might get difficult as we decide to support more and more languages??

I would really appreciate any expert suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the locale dynamically you could test the package [Angular Dynamic Locale](http://lgalfaso.github.io/angular-dynamic-locale/).